# How to swap tabs, change the order of the tabs in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser-tabs

I use Windows 10 and have a question.

I want to ask how to change the tabs, I am not sure how its even called so I made a picture from it.

[image: What tab or window I mean]

So these two are tabs or windows but that is just an example, lets say one of them is called New Tab 1 and the other one is called New Tab 2.

How would I change the order of it?

As example: It got swapped for some reason to New Tab 2, New Tab 1. How would I change it and make it say again

New Tab 1, New Tab 2. Can anybody help me or do you need a more explaining to this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, all you wish to do is change the order, correct? Left click and hold Tab 1 and move it over to the beginning of Tab 2. If your tabs are actual websites that you're wishing to keep as tabs, just pin it (right click on the tab and select "PIN")

Comment: I guess you understand something wrong.

Comment: I am not talking about task bars, when you click one of these icons it opens or shows your current windows or window.